# Вывести свойства объектов содержащихся в списке? ООП. Наследование

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп

Изучаю Python, написал вот такой код:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def ShowData(self):
        print (self.name)


class Student(Person):
    def __init__(self, name, education):
        # super().__init__(self, name)
        self.education = education


class Worker(Person):
    def __init__(self, workPlace):
        self.workPlace = workPlace


class Academy:
    def __init__(self):
        # при создании объекта инициализируем пустой список
        self.persons = []

    def show_all(self):
        # Output collection
        for pers in self.persons:
            for atr in dir(pers):
                if atr == 'education':
                    print(pers.name, pers.education)
                elif atr == 'work_place':
                    print(pers.name, pers.work_place)
                else:
                    continue

            print(pers.name)

    def AddPerson(self,pers):
        # Добавляем объект в коллекцию
        self.persons.append(pers)
```

> Подскажите как унаследовать конструктор класса `Person` так, чтобы работал следующий код:

```
man = Person("Mark")
st  = Student("Deyve", "History")
#man.ShowData()
print("_________________")
nmu = Academy()
nmu.AddPerson(man)
nmu.AddPerson(st)
nmu.ShowAll()
```

На данном этапе ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 35, in <module>
  File "python", line 23, in ShowAll
AttributeError: 'Student' object has no attribute 'name'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно было просто вызывать конструктор класса-предка.

*Используйте другой стиль именования методов и полей: в нижнем регистре, разделяя слова нижним подчеркиванием – так принято для питона ([pep 8](http://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/pep-8-rukovodstvo-po-napisaniyu-koda-na-python.html))*

Пример:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def show_data(self):
        print(self.name)


class Student(Person):
    def __init__(self, name, education):
        super().__init__(name)
        self.education = education


class Worker(Person):
    def __init__(self, name, work_place):
        super().__init__(name)
        self.work_place = work_place


class Academy:
    def __init__(self):
        # При создании объекта инициализируем пустой список
        self.persons = []

    def show_all(self):
        # Output collection
        for pers in self.persons:
            if isinstance(pers, Student):
                print('is student: ' + pers.name)

            elif isinstance(pers, Worker):
                print('is worker: ' + pers.name)

            elif isinstance(pers, Person):
                print('is person: ' + pers.name)

    def add_person(self,pers):
        # Добавляем объект в коллекцию
        self.persons.append(pers)


man = Person("Mark")
st  = Student("Deyve", "History")

print("_________________")
nmu = Academy()
nmu.add_person(man)
nmu.add_person(st)
nmu.show_all()
```

Консоль:

```
_________________
is person: Mark
is student: Deyve
```

Comment: а как выводить свойства объектов в методе show_all(), если объекты разных классов с разным набором атрибутов? У меня две мысли, либо есть стандартный способ получения значений всех атрибутов объекта(который у меня не получилось нагуглить), либо нужно каким-то образом через условие проверять объектом какого класса является объект и выводить значения атрибутов объекта конкретного класса(но это менее универсально чем хотелось бы)

Comment: я переписал метод 'show_all()', он выводит, но с избытком теперь... Метод исправил в вопросе, можете подсказать что не так?

Comment: Используйте `isinstance` чтобы определить тип объекта. Я обновлю ответ, чтобы показать что имею ввиду. При проверке нужно, чтобы проверка на `Person` была последней, потому что и классы объектов `Student` и `Worker` являются потомками `Person` и всегда `isinstance(pers, Person)` будет возвращать `True`